# Is there a way to configure GatsbyJS build process to insert <style> tags at the bottom of the <head> tags?

Tags: gatsby, share-open-graph

I'm experiencing a weird bug with Slack opengraph unfurling where no meta tags are shown because the style-tag is inserted at the beginning of the head-tag.

My project is built on this kit: https://github.com/vincenterc/gatsby-starter-p5 and style.scss is inserted in the layout-component

This is the site I'm working on: https://bionicsearch.net

And here's a working example where I have manually moved the style-tag to the bottom: 
https://manual-test.andersnaero.now.sh

I'd really appreciate your help on this :)

Comment: Does changing the order of plugins in `gatsby-config.js` change anything?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Look into onPreRenderHTML in gatsby-ssr, you can change order of tags in head there IIRC

Comment: I solved this by creating an index.js file and adding meta-tags manually.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating an index.js file and adding meta-tags manually. Here are instructions on how to do this: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/